# Manjaro guest on VirtualBox not able to get the full resolution

Tags: windows, virtualbox, manjaro, resolution

## What I have

1. Host: Windows 10 Version 1803
2. Guest: 4.19.20-1-MANJARO
3. VirtualBox Version 6.0.4r128413

## What I have tried:

1. using the VirtualBox geustaddition iso

   1.1. from toolbar `Devices > Insert guestaddition image ...`

   1.2. `cd /run/media/foobar/VBox_GAs-6.0.4`

   1.3. `sudo sh autorun.sh` or simply by `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` leading to the error:

> This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
>   Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
>   for adding new hardware support to the system.
>   VirtualBox Guest Additions: modprobe vboxsf failed

1.4. So I tried solving the problem by installing the Linux kernel header files as mentioned [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox#Guest_Installation):

1.4.1 find the Linux kernel by `mhwd-kernel -li` which in my case is `linux419`

1.4.2. Then `sudo pacman -S linux419-kernel`

1.4.3. then following the step one in original post and reboot. This solves the resolution problem but every time I reboot I have to wait for 5-6 minutes showing the message:

> A stop job is running for vboxadd.service …
>
> [image]

1.4.4. Tried the `sudo systemctl stop vboxadd` and `sudo systemctl disable vboxadd` from [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/virtualbox-6-slow-start-shutdown/70627/22) but then it reverts the resolution back.

1.4.5. tried uninstalling the guest additions by `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run uninstall` and then following step 2 whish was also not successful!

2. using the Manjaro repository as suggested on their [wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=VirtualBox#Guest_Installation):

   2.1. `sudo pacman -Syu virtualbox-guest-utils` leading to

> There are 11 providers available for VIRTUALBOX-HOST-MODULES:
>
> :: Repository extra
>
> 1. linux316-virtualbox-guest-modules
>
> …
>
> :: Repository community
>
> linux-rt-lts-manjaro-virtualbox-guest-modules

2.2. from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j7ZN.png) running `mhwd-kernel -li` indicates that should go for `linux419`, or use `sudo pacman -S linux419-virtualbox-guest-modules` instead. but then I get the error:

> error failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
>
> virtualbox guest utils exists in filesystem vboxclient

2.3. as suggested here I tried `sudo pacman -S --force` and finished the installation and rebooted. But nothing changes except that I get this notification:

> [image]

Answer (score 20):

To get Auto-Resize Guest Display working you have to use **'VBoxSVGA'**

1. Stop VM if installed and running
2. Choose in VM Setting: Display > Screen > Graphics Controller > **'VBoxSVGA'**
3. Save
4. Start VM with Manjaro - **Screen goes black**.
5. hit **CTRL+ALT+F2** to enter tty2
6. logon
7. **sudo mhwd -r pci video-vmware**
8. reboot

Resizing works like a charm.

Tested on Linux, Mac OS and Windows 10

(In older versions of Virtual Box, the controller was VBoxVGA, but this is deprecated since version 6.0 and no longer available in 6.1.)

Comment: This should be the chosen answer for the latest version, worked perfectly.

Comment: This really saved my day. I tried a lot of answers, only this one works.

Comment: This answer works in the new version.

Comment: This worked for me too.   I'd like to know what it actually *does* though!  What is video-vmware?

Comment: Actually, using the VBoxSVGA disabled the shared clipboard for me.   So I uninstalled virtualbox-guest-utils and went back to the Guest Additions ISO.  That got me resizing with the VMSVGA driver, and the shared clipboard working too.  See @andselisk's answer.

Comment: @ChillyPenguin I had the same problem and upgraded now to Virtualbox 6.1 and VBoxSVGA with 256MB + 3D acc and clipboard working like a charm.

Comment: @ChillyPenguin vmware-video is VMSVGA which was broken before. seems like it is working now ^^

Comment: I also experience I have to chose VBoxSVGA mode to get things working, but then I get a warning "VM is configured with different graphics controller than recommended", any idea why this is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 13):

I recently faced the same issue, and after some research I came up with the solution that doesn't require to use `VBoxVGA` adapter and reinstall Manjaro.
The TL;DR version is, you needed to install `linux419-headers`, not `linux419-kernel`.

#### System specs

**Host**: Windows 10 1809 Pro 64 bit
**Guest**: Manjaro KDE 18.0.4 64 bit with 4.19.34-1-MANJARO kernel
**Virtualization**: VirtualBox 6.0.6 r130049 (Qt5.6.2)

#### Steps

1. Do full system update:
   `sudo pacman -Syyu`
2. Install `gcc`, `make` and Linux kernel "header" files for the current kernel version (which can be found via `uname -r` command, e.g. `linux419-headers` – I tried to provide a uniform command using `sed` and `grep` functionality):
   `sudo pacman -S gcc make linux$(uname -r|sed 's/\W//g'|cut -c1-2)-headers`
3. Reboot:
   `sudo reboot`
4. Mount the ISO via *Devices → Guest Additions CD Image…* and open the terminal there.
5. Run
   `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
6. Reboot:
   `sudo reboot`

At this point Manjaro should work fine with the new `VMSVGA` controller adjusting screen resolution on the fly (make sure you allocated enough video memory (128 Mb) and enabled acceleration in VM settings beforehand), seamlessly share buffer and allow drag-and-drop.

#### Update

Recent kernel update from `4.19.34-1-MANJARO` to `5.0.9-2-MANJARO` didn't affect functionality of Guest Additions and no additional tweaking was required:

[image: Screenshot of an arbitrary resolution of updated kernel]

Comment: For me the 'uniform command' didn't work to install the headers, I just got `error: target not found: linux521-headers`, however running `sudo pacman -S linux52-headers` did work and installed `linux52-headers-5.2.11-1`.

Comment: @nakamin Thank you, I corrected the command (crop to two instead of three numbers in kernel version). Probably package naming changed with the release of kernel version 5.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this working (Mac OS Mojave Host, latest Manjaro w 5.4 kernel). I can change resolution on the guest manually but bizarrely it doesn;t offer the native resolution of my screen (1440) as an option. It also doesn't resize automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The last post in the forum which [meepmeep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511779/358805) linked in his answer did the trick for me:

> 1. installing the correct driver and uninstalling the incorrect one
>
>    ```
>    mhwd -i pci video-virtualbox
>    mhwd -r pci video-vmware
>    ```
> 2. shutdown and change the VM graphics controller to VboxVGA

Comment: In addition to this, I need to install guest addition utils `sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-utils`.

Comment: I get 'video-virtualbox' does not exist when attempting this.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is making sure your VB session is NOT running. Got to its settings and click on Display > Screen > and under 'Graphics Controller' pull down the menu and select 'VBoxVGA'. Save and exit, and restart your VB session.

Comment: I tried this and now the screen is all black!

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem, and have failed to resolve this in similar steps. The issue seems to be with the graphics controller option introduced in Virtualbox 6.0.

I found that if you create a fresh installation using the 'VBoxVGA' controller from the very beginning, then everything works correctly, but if you install using the default 'VMSVGA' controller then it doesn't seem to be possible to revert/fix any of the issues through any obvious means.

See more info here also with a possible suggestion on fixing an existing installation (though only setting the option at installation worked for me): https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cant-auto-resize-guest-display-in-virtualbox/78030/9