# Issue while booting Kubuntu on VirtualBox: drm vmw_host_log vmwgfx error failed to send log

Tags: boot, virtualbox, kubuntu

I have installed Kubbuntu as guest one virtualbox on Windows 10 and now when I want to boot it take a long time showing this message:

[image]

> [drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send log

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I do see the same when I start Ubuntu 18.10 on Oracle VirtualBox 6.0.4 (Windows 10) but _this does not slow down the boot process_ and I did not see any other adverse effect. It would still be interesting to understand what it means.

Comment: @Mike well in my case it is quite annoying. I have to wait a couple of minutes to boot! Ubuntu is fine though. I have this issue only on Kubuntu. I haven't had much like with KDE in general [recently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499938/manjaro-guest-on-virtualbox-not-able-to-get-the-full-resolution)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "drm:vmw\_host\_log \[vmwgfx\]\] \*ERROR\* Failed to send host log message" show up and what can I do to fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh)

Comment: This question was asked before the linked question, but the correct fix is in an answer on that thread.

Comment: Perhaps this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1648527/increasing-screen-resolution-of-linux-terminal-using-grub2/1648529#1648529) may help to solve the issue. https://superuser.com/questions/1648527/increasing-screen-resolution-of-linux-terminal-using-grub2/1648529#1648529