# systemd-journald[387] Failed to write file entry

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am on a windows machine, running linux mint mate from a virtual machine.
While in boot I get the following errors

[image: error]

I have no access to the kernal so I can't execute any commands that I have seen in other posts.

Might cause the problem but I don't really know:
Lately I updated my windows version and installed wsl2

Am I doomed?

EDIT:
when I am trying to boot now, I am get the following error
[image]

Comment: Something is causing / to be mounted read-only; until that's fixed, you won't get any farther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the image given by you the grub is providing you a initramfs prompt, basically the bootloader is able to load the the above prompt but there would be possibility of corrupted partition of linux, which is not allowing the root directory '\' to be mounted.

i would prefer to run the [fsck command](https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)

you can refer to these links for further help:

1. [initramfs prompt](https://askubuntu.com/a/817660)
2. [graphic problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503733) (i am not sure this would be a problem)

[initramfs information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs)