# Kali Linux returns terminal screen after updating VirtualBox

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox

today I decided to update my virtual box from version 6.0.14 to the newest version 6.1.16
With it, I also downloaded the extension pack for version 6.1.16, replacing the old 6.0.14 extension pack.
Kali Linux was already installed on the old version and transferred to the new version of virtualbox. So, after my update, I decided to try and run Kali Linux to make sure it works. This is what I see as soon as I run Kali Linux :
[image]

As you can see from the picture, the kali linux virtual machine is now just booting up a terminal.

I tried going back to the old virtual box and I installed the old extension pack again, but it did not work.

Comment: it's a [duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/502540/436188).
Please check the link for your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "drm:vmw\_host\_log \[vmwgfx\]\] \*ERROR\* Failed to send host log message" show up and what can I do to fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the following commands in the terminal: `fsck /dev/sda1` and then just keep pressing `y` until it the questions are finished. Then, just restart your virtual machine and you are good to go!

Comment: Why not `fsck -y /dev/sda1`?