# Ubuntu stucked while starting with Black Screen

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, startup

Last night my Ubuntu VM was working fine, but today its not starting up. I don't know why it isn't starting up.

I am using **Oracle VM Box 6.1** and I have **Ubuntu 20.04**.
It starts up and then stucks after showing [OK] messages.

I have recorded the video to clearly show the steps:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1p2g7vh53nalxl/LX_VM_Startup_Issue2.mp4?dl=0

I have no idea to fix this.

Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you get before the Ubuntu "loading" starts this thread might be of some help: [Why does "drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message" show up and what can I do to fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502540/why-does-drmvmw-host-log-vmwgfx-error-failed-to-send-host-log-message-sh)

Additionally I believe you can hit the Escape key once the loading starts to get a running of the boot process, which might give more info on any other possible errors.